# Land Rover Defender L316 2.4TCDi starts and stalls almost immediately does not idle

Tags: diesel, idle, stall, land-rover

2010
Land Rover Defender
L313 platform

Vehicle almost as good as new

less than 20,000KM on the odometer

Bought brand new a few years back with just 10KM on the odometer

Has done just two oil changes since purchase

Has a 2.4 TDI Puma/Ford/LR diesel engine

Any ideas how to begin to troubleshoot this?

There are absolutely no codes to rely on!

Comment: Partially blocked exhaust pipe? That won't stop the engine firing, but the back pressure will stop it running. Try disconnecting the exhaust from the block, as an experiment (warning - if that fixes the problem, the result will be LOUD).

Comment: @alephzero never thought of that...an interesting proposition... will try it out and provide feedback

Comment: Before taking off the exhaust, you should read the codes as they may give a better insight to the real issue...

Comment: Does it have a dpf?

Comment: It has thrown absolutely no codes

Comment: So have you used the continuous reading function to see what is happening - helped me when I was trying to work out a low power issue...

Comment: @SolarMike No DPF

Comment: Mine did not have any codes but the continuous readings told the story - and it’s a jaguar...

Comment: @SolarMike Do you mean OBD II "Continuous or Non-continuous Monitors"? I am lost what you mean by continuous reading function!

Comment: Live data ie continuous readout

Comment: Was the vehicle left unused for a long time, say months?  Or, was it running just fine yesterday and this problem happened suddenly?

Comment: @Carguy Always in use...died at a traffic stop...two days after an oil change

Comment: Starting easily and almost immediately stopping sounds like failure of the immobilizer antenna or wiring. But I don't know if this vehicle has an immobilizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of common things with the Puma that cause a non start.

1. Fuel Pressure Relief Valve which is on the high pressure pump
2. Fuel Metering solenoid which is on the fuel rail
3. Immobiliser if fitted

Using live data on a diagnostic tool will point you in the right direction with the above.